# How to create dictionary new array with the data? Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Example:

```
var people: [(name: String, age: Int)] = [("Tim", "23"), ("Tom","28"), ("John", "35")]
```

In a new array named "Names" that should do look like this:

```
Names = ["Tim", "Tom", "John"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to achieve that:

```
let people: [(name: String, age: Int)] = [("Tim", 23), ("Tom", 28), ("John", 35)]
let names = people.map({ $0.name })
```

And by the way, what you have is an array of tuples, not a dictionary.

Each tuple contains 2 values: a `String` which is named `name` and an `Int` which is named `age`.

`age` is `Int` not `String`, so you need to use integers for `age` inside tuples, not strings.

Comment: Thank you! You've been very helpful!

Comment: I was in a hurry and made a mistake with "age"))))

Comment: You're welcome :D If my answer helped you consider accepting it please.